# Running GCM on real device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have create an android application using GCM service feature, but it cannot run on real device. Do I need to sign up as google developer first?

Comment: Do the emulator and device you are using have the same Android version?  Which version is it?

Comment: its different, I use 4.3.3 on emulator, but the real device I have is 4.04

Answer (score 0):

For a internal use, you don't have to sign up as Google Developer.
Using GCM, you should read http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: I have create an application with GCM, and run well on emulator, but cannot work on real device

Comment: In my case, it is working both emulator and real device. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#run

Answer (score 0):

If by "running GCM" you mean being able to send messages from your server to Google's then you'd need one account to access and enable the service via the Google API console.

Otherwise, a Google account is not needed for client Android devices running 4.0.4, but necessary for those on earlier versions. For more information, you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html).

Comment: The problem is, I can send GCM message from my server to emulator device, but cannot send it to real device, thats why I asked if I need google developer account to bring it to real device?